# implementation of LZ77 and Direct2 encoding algorithm

Tags: algorithm, compression, implementation

I need to find the implementation of LZ77 and Direct2 algorithms as describe at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425493%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) website. I was expecting that it might be part of an SDK. So far, I have had no luck.

Can someone please guide me to where I can find these algorithms so that I can use them in my code?

Thank you

Comment: What's broken with your search engine of choice? having tried with several different languages this answer can be found in seconds with a search for `"LZ77 <programming language of choice>"`

Comment: MSDN docs say that their implementation of the algorithm is a bit tweaked. So that is why I was looking for the exact things. Otherwise I would have not posted here.

Comment: my experience with their version of LZFU was just they 'tweaked' it just by removing one xor, if you have a starting point like those source you can find the rest is just reading the msdn doc and seeing if the code matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple search with google yields:

- [wikipedia - LZ77 and LZ78](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78)
- [DIRECT2 Encoding Algorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee896247%28v=prot.13%29.aspx)

And I hope you aren't asking for the code itself.

Comment: Was looking for an implementation. Open or closed source did not matter.

Comment: oK cOOl. but still looking for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you found a solution?
I have with help from Michael Cohen translated this to C# for decompression.
http://volatility.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1609/branches/scudette/contrib/pyxpress/pyxpress.c

My tests indicates that it works fine, but test for your self :)

```
    private static int PAGE_SIZE = 0x00001000;
    private static int XPRESS_ENCODE_MAGIC = 0x19880922;
    private static int DELTA_PAGE = ((2 * PAGE_SIZE) - 1);
    private static int UNCOMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE = (PAGE_SIZE * 0x10);



    public static byte[] Xpress_Decompress(byte[] inputBuffer, int outputSize)
    {
        int outputIndex, inputIndex;
        int indicator, indicatorBit;
        int length;
        int offset;
        int nibbleIndex;
        int nibbleIndicator;
        int inputSize = inputBuffer.Length;

        outputIndex = 0;
        inputIndex = 0;
        indicator = 0;
        indicatorBit = 0;
        length = 0;
        offset = 0;
        nibbleIndex = 0;
        nibbleIndicator = XPRESS_ENCODE_MAGIC;

        var outputBuffer = new byte[outputSize];
        while ((outputIndex < outputSize) && (inputIndex < inputSize))
        {
            if (indicatorBit == 0)
            {
                if (inputIndex + 3 >= inputSize) goto Done;
                indicator = GetInt(inputBuffer, inputIndex);
                inputIndex += sizeof(int);
                indicatorBit = 32;
            }
            indicatorBit--;

            //* check whether the bit specified by IndicatorBit is set or not
            //* set in Indicator. For example, if IndicatorBit has value 4
            //* check whether the 4th bit of the value in Indicator is set

            if (((indicator >> indicatorBit) & 1) == 0)
            {
                if (outputIndex >= outputSize) 
                    goto Done;
                outputBuffer[outputIndex] = inputBuffer[inputIndex];
                inputIndex += sizeof(byte);
                outputIndex += sizeof(byte);
            }
            else
            {
                if (inputIndex + 1 >= inputSize) 
                    goto Done;
                length = (inputBuffer[inputIndex + 1] << 8) | inputBuffer[inputIndex];

                /*
                if ((OutputIndex > 0xD0) && (OutputIndex < 0xF0))
                {
                    printf("DECOMP: READ AT [0x%08X] = %04X \n", InputIndex, Length);
                }
                */
                inputIndex += sizeof(ushort);
                offset = length / 8;
                length = length % 8;
                //if ((OutputIndex > 0xD0) && (OutputIndex < 0xF0)) printf("--1 Len: %02X (%d)\n", Length, Length);
                if (length == 7)
                {
                    if (nibbleIndex == 0)
                    {
                        nibbleIndex = inputIndex;
                        if (inputIndex >= inputSize) 
                            goto Done;
                        length = inputBuffer[inputIndex] % 16;
                        //if ((OutputIndex > 0xD0) && (OutputIndex < 0xF0)) printf("--2 Len: %02X (%d)\n", Length, Length);
                        inputIndex += sizeof(byte);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        length = inputBuffer[nibbleIndex] / 16;
                        //if ((OutputIndex > 0xD0) && (OutputIndex < 0xF0)) printf("--3 Len: %02X (%d)\n", Length, Length);
                        nibbleIndex = 0;
                    }

                    if (length == 15)
                    {
                        if (inputIndex >= inputSize) goto Done;
                        length = inputBuffer[inputIndex];
                        //if ((OutputIndex > 0xD0) && (OutputIndex < 0xF0)) printf("--4 Len: %02X (%d)\n", Length, Length);
                        inputIndex += sizeof(byte);
                        if (length == 255)
                        {
                            if (inputIndex + 2 >= inputSize) goto Done;
                            length = (inputBuffer[inputIndex + 1] << 8) | inputBuffer[inputIndex];
                            inputIndex += sizeof(ushort);
                            length -= (15 + 7);
                        }
                        length += 15;
                        //if ((OutputIndex > 0xD0) && (OutputIndex < 0xF0)) printf("--5 Len: %02X (%d)\n", Length, Length);
                    }
                    length += 7;
                    //if ((OutputIndex > 0xD0) && (OutputIndex < 0xF0)) printf("--6 Len: %02X (%d)\n", Length, Length);
                }

                length += 3;
                //if ((OutputIndex > 0xD0) && (OutputIndex < 0xF0)) printf("--7 Len: %02X (%d)\n", Length, Length);
                //if (Length > 280) printf("DECOMP DEBUG: [0x%08X]->[0x%08X] Len: %d Offset: %08X\n",
                //    OutputIndex, InputIndex, Length, Offset);
                while (length != 0)
                {
                    if ((outputIndex >= outputSize) || ((offset + 1) >= outputIndex)) break;
                    outputBuffer[outputIndex] = outputBuffer[outputIndex - offset - 1];
                    outputIndex += sizeof(byte);
                    length -= sizeof(byte);
                }
            }

        }

    Done:

        if (outputIndex < outputBuffer.Length)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[outputIndex];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(outputBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, outputIndex);
            outputBuffer = buffer;
        }


        return outputBuffer;
    }

    public static int GetInt(byte[] buffer, int offset)
    {
        return
            ((int)buffer[offset]) |
            ((int)buffer[offset + 1] << 8) |
            ((int)buffer[offset + 2] << 16) |
            ((int)buffer[offset + 3] << 24);
    }
```